# Break Arabic Font

Tags: android, webview, font-face, arabic

I am making android app in which I have to give support of Arabic text to those mobiles in which Arabic is not present.

I successfully did this in widgets(textview, button etc) by adding following code.

I ahve added `dejavusans.ttf` file in assests folder.
and in code I added

```
    TypeFace typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "dejavusans.ttf"); 
fieldName.setTypeface(typeFace);   
fieldName.setText(ArabicUtilities.reshape(resources.getString(R.string.bring_financial_arabic)));
```

But the problem is with WebView. The text of webView is breaking. I saw different solutions including [How to change font face of Webview in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900658/how-to-change-font-face-of-webview-in-android). But no one is working fine.
Here is the snapshot.[image]
The title(TextView) is looking fine but the webpage text is breaking.

If anyone know its answer then please help.

Thanks

Comment: Check which version of Android and WebKit you have. Older versions are not able to render Arabic even if you supply a font.

Comment: I am using 2.2 version and webkit is 533.1. The problem is with web page text only. The text of textview, edittext, buttons are fine in Arabic by using above method.

Comment: @zeeshan0026 Have you solved the problem? We're running into the same problem on Android 2.3 now. Hope you can answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution of  this problem.

I used the following tool http://www.arabic-keyboard.org/photoshop-arabic/

I pasted my arabic in it and copy the result then I pasted the result in my html file. The result is like this.

[image]

Although it is not 100 percent accurate but it is much better than previous one.

Answer (score 0):

U can use adobe indesign for your arabic text and after paste all paragraph text to indesign , you should copy, then paste to photoshop from adobe indesign, every texts will be Okay.